# Animating multiple divs in a loop using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm having three blue squares on my webpage. Each square is 50px by 50px in size. I wish to slowly increase the size of each squares to 80px by 80px one after the other. 
Instead of the expected result above, only the last square size got changed.

Please how can I get the code below to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>zoom box</title>
  <script>
    function zoom() {
      var box;
      const height = 50;
      var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
      var id;
      for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        box = boxes[i];
        h = height;
        frame();
      }

      function frame() {
        h++;
        if (h >= 80) {
          return;
        }

        box.style.height = h + 'px';
        box.style.width = h + 'px';

        setTimeout(frame, 100);

      }
    }
  </script>

  <head>

    <body width="100%" height="100%" onload="zoom()">
      <div style="width: 20em; height: 20em; margin:auto; border-style:solid;display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">

        <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; width:50px; height: 50px; margin:auto">

        </div>

        <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; width:50px; height: 50px; margin:auto">

        </div>

        <div class="box" style="background-color: blue; width:50px; height: 50px; margin:auto">

        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pass the box object into the frame() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function zoom() {
      var box;
      const height = 50;
      var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
      var array = [];
      var id;
      for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        box = boxes[i];
        console.log(box)
        h = height;
        if(i == 0){
            array[i] = true;
        }else{
            array[i] = false;
        }
        frame(box,i,height);
    }

      function frame(box,i,h) {


        if (h >= 80) {
          for(var j  = 0; j < array.length ; j++){
            if(j != i && array[j] == false){
                array[j] = true;
                break;
            }
          }
          array[i] = true;
          return box;
        }
        console.log(i + " " + array[i]);
        if(array[i]){
            h++;
            box.style.height = h + 'px';
            box.style.width = h + 'px';
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            frame(box,i,h);
        }, 100);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. all the boxes size changed all at once. I would love to have it change one after the other i.e first box should zoom first, followed by the second, then the third. Thanks once again

Comment: Would appreciate a short explanation on what you did. Thank you